# VS2010 Add-in cpp/h automatic tab groups

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, add-in

Is there any Visual Studio 2010 add-in that will automatically group cpp and header files in different tab-groups, and also maybe automatically open/close corresponding cpp/header files when opening a certain file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This addin looks like providing the first feature that you wanted, though I don't know whether it works with h/cpp files: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/EBF6137E-AA2D-4DC9-860A-F04168F11CD7.

About the second, I'm not sure you really always want to do. I think most of the time that can actually be annoying since you'd end up closing files you never needed to look at.